# Autoresizing of a custom view in a scrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, autoresizingmask

I have created a custom view which is loaded from a xib file like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TachoView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
    [self initUi];
  }
  return self;
}
```

I am now experiencing problems with the autoresizing and positioning of some subviews, when the device orientation changes. These screenshots describe the behaviour.

After viewDidLoad everything looks fine:

[image]

After the rotation to landscape mode, the layout is still fine:

[image]

But when rotating back to protrait, it looks like this:

[image]

The same files .h, .m and .xib work fine, if I test them in a single view dummy project. So I think, the settings for positioning and resizing in the xib are ok. The difference to my app is, that the view is positioned on a scrollview with several other views. On orientation change, I change the size of all these views, so that everything is layouted as expected. The relevant code is the innermost for-loop:

```
-(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    float h = self.view.frame.size.height;
    float w = self.view.frame.size.width;

    // set the size of the vertical scrollview
    verticalView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h * gridHeight);
    verticalScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
    [verticalScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(w, h * gridHeight)];
    [verticalScrollView layoutIfNeeded];

    // set the size of the horizontal scrollviews
    for (int i=0; i<verticalView.subviews.count; i++) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *) [verticalView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        UIView *container = (UIView *) [[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        int subviewCount = container.subviews.count;
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, h*i, w, h);
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(w * subviewCount, h)];
        container.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w * subviewCount, h);

        // set the size of the actual views
        for (int j=0; j<container.subviews.count; j++) {
            UIView *view = [container.subviews objectAtIndex:j];
            // FIXME manchmal crashed hier die WebView. Muss das hier im
            // ui thread ausgeführt werden? wird diese methode nicht vom
            // ui thread aufgerufen?
            view.frame = CGRectMake(w*j, 0, w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea, what's going wrong with the second orientation change? I could layout the whole view manually, but I think it is possible with the autoresizing functionality, too.

Comment: posting the screenshots of your .xib will be helpful.

Comment: I have uploaded screenshot of IB: http://imgur.com/4R9VE,MTvvl,oO1I1,bNNsu,lIlov,ChXtL

Comment: is the label a subview of your TachoView? or is there another view in the heirarchy between these two views?

Comment: actually the hierarchy is NavigationView -> Scrollview (vertical) -> Scrollview (horizontal) -> TachoView -> Container view (for background color) -> labels

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the UIViewAutoresizingMasks are set like these

1) Liegezeiten label is flexibleWidth

2) the Wert in % label needs to have only flexibleTopMargin, flexibleWidth and flexibleRightMargin

3) the number labels below (64, 40, 20):

- 64 should have flexibleTopMargin, flexibleWidth and
  flexibleRightMargin
- 40 should have flexibleTopMargin, flexibleWidth,
  flexibleRightMargin,  flexibleLeftMargin
- 20 should have flexibleTopMargin, flexibleWidth,
  flexibleLeftMargin

Comment: I'm not sure what these values would be in interface builder, so I set them programatically. Unfortunately without any effect. Also, see my comment above for some screenshots of the IB settings. Thanks.

Comment: Please also notice, that the exact same files work as expected in a single view app. So my settings should be right, or?

Comment: are you doing all the resizing and repositioning programmatically without using UIViewAutoresizingmasks?

Comment: The resizing is done only on the TachoView itself. The subviews are not touched. They shall be resized/positioned automatically according to the size change of TachoView.

Comment: I am not sure where its going wrong, but I'd guess its going wrong in the viewWillLayoutSubviews, which may be called a little too early/late for your calculations. Or, your subviews are not really indexed the way you are thinking, when you do  "for (int j=0; j<container.subviews.count; j++)"